# CSS Fill 100% of height. Different Browser Sizes

Tags: css, html, height

I have a sidebar(blue) which is set to float left. I've set the height to 100% and body and html height set to 100%. It works fine:

[image]

The problem is when the browser is smaller than the content pane div (red), the height of the sidebar becomes the same height as the browser. So if i scroll down, the side bar is shorter than the page:

[image]

The body adjusts itself though, its height covers the content pane. But I guess the height of the sidebar is the height of the window because, it's set to 100% of the body which is set to 100% of the html which is set to 100% of the window. I can take out 100% height for the body and html but that means I can't set the height of the side bar, which will make it as short as possible.

I'm really stumped here. Any help would be appreciated

html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='menubar'>ignore this for now</div>
<div id='sidebar'>a few elements<div>
<div id='contentPane'>lots of elements</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html,body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
}

#sidebar{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

### SOLUTION

Hashem Qolami solved this by wrapping the divs and using absolute positioning for the side pane

html:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id='menubar'>note the height of this element</div>
    <div id='sidebar'>a few elements</div>
    <div id='contentPane'>a lot of elements</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
html,body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: gold;
}

#menubar {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;   /*HEIGHT OF THE MENU BAR*/
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#contentPane {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/hashem/J4WW9](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/J4WW9)

Comment: Have you tried `min-height: 100%;` ?

Comment: Never mind. Now I see that it's not an issue of the content being cut off. Sorry.

Comment: Can you wrap the sidebar and content pane in a div with a min-height of 100%, then use a 100% height on the sidebar?

Comment: without setting a height for the div container, the sidebar will be as short as it can. min-height doesn't give the same effect as height. on firefox at least

Comment: @karunchaudhary Does the header have an explicit height?

Comment: about 30px. Although it's a non-issue, similar to Anthony's suggestion, I could wrap the sidebar and content pane in a dive to eliminate its effect.

Comment: @karunchaudhary I was trying to achieve the same effect by using absolute positioning. And in this case it would be an issue :) Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/J4WW9/

Comment: Perfect! I did try to use absolute earlier but I didn't put the relative positioning in the container. I guess you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @karunchaudhary I'm glad I could help. You could post the correct answer to help the others having the same issue.

Comment: One more thing Hashem, the nuances of css are lost on me. Without the relative position on the container, the sidebar's bottom is the bottom of the window. How does relative position fix that?

Comment: @karunchaudhary Good question. That's a long story :) but in short, the position of absolutely positioned elements is relative to its closest **non-static positioned** ancestor or to the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block) *(`absolute` and `relative` position types create a containing block to the absolutely positioned descendants)* Hence if we don't create a containing block for the positioned element, it [will be positioned relative to the root element](http://jsbin.com/mufon/1/edit) of the document which is the `<html>` element.

Comment: In this particularly instance, the `<html>` has a height of `100%` of the viewport. Take a look at red dashed line in: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/J4WW9/1/ The absolutely positioned box sticks at the bottom of the `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I manage to do this is by creating a div that surrounds both sideBar and contentPane.

[Here](http://cdpn.io/HlFKg)'s a pen to demonstrate!